# Looking for JWT Auth microservice example

Tags: node.js, authorization, jwt, microservices

I am wanting to build a authentication/authorization service using NodeJS, Mongo, and JWT.  This service would be a micro-service that handles requests not only from my API Gateway before allowing requests, but from other services that might want to check auth and roles. I am assuming that all other services will use this Auth Service to validate the JWT as well as roles, etc.

Hopefully this diagram better explains what I am looking for.
[image]

Can anyone point me to a resource that might help me learn how to do this with NodeJS?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**If you have a single client application then you can do following steps**

- Make one microservice for authentication that generates jwt token.
- The jwt contains all essential user information in its payload, ie Role, UserId etc.
- The jwt token will be sent in Authorization header for every authorised request.
- Before processing any request you can validate and decode the jwt token using middlewares. Now you can set the user's info in req object easliy and can easily access users role and its id in your controller.
- if the token is not valid then you can throw error in middlewares and it will provide json response of unauthorised.
- You can call the authentication api to validate and decode your token or you can write 3 to 4 line of code in every microservice in middleware.

Here are some links for sample implementation of jwt, you should customize these sample code according to above steps.

[5-steps-to-authenticating-node-js](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/5-steps-to-authenticating-node-js-with-jwt-7ahb5dmyr)

[authenticate a nodejs api with json web tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)

**If you have multiple client applications**

- You should use openid connect standard that provides single sign on solution to authenticate multiple application with same username and password.
- [here](https://openidconnect.net/) is a openid connect playground to understand the authorization flow.

Comment: @sonoerin i have explained some steps, tell me if u having some doubts or this is your usecase or not.

Comment: Thank you I will start looking at how I can use JWT with a single client and multiple services that pass the JWT between services and UI in the AuthorizationHeader.

Comment: For the last point related to decoding JWT in every microservice in middleware, we would need to share the secret key with every microservice, isn't it ? Is it ok? what would be a good way to do that ?

Comment: Yes we need to share the secret key with every microservice, the best way is to provide jwks url which contains public keys. You can refer [here](https://auth0.com/docs/jwks)

Comment: @gaurav5430 Decoding of JWT doesn't require any key. But if you wan to *verify* jwt. It will require the public key. The auth server should have a endpoint that checks jwt validity. In that case just calling the auth server with provided key should do the trick. It requires a round trip but should be mostly okay if the auth service is in same cluster.

Comment: But how does revoking the token should work in this scenario? Lets say i want a feature to revoke the token.Microservice would have to talk to Auth service every time it goes through every request.

Comment: I had a similar requirement (of invalidating tokens) and used the Refresh Token design pattern